# Using Vuex getters, inside other computed properties

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I have created some getter in my store and mapped them using `mapGetters`, as per the below, the data within them is correct as seen in the Vue debug tool.

Now I am using this data to create some computed properties for pagination as the below. But I am not sure why the errors are showing that the getter is returning undefined.

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      pageNumber: 1
    }
  },
  props: {
    size: {
      type: Number,
      required: false,
      default: 5
    }
  },
  methods: {
    nextPage() {
      this.pageNumber++
    },
    prevPage() {
      this.pageNumber--
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters([
      'getCurrentClientConfig',
      'getFullVendorList'
    ]),
    totalVendors() {
      return getFullVendorList.vendors.length;
    },
    pageCount() {
      let l = getFullVendorList.vendors.length;
      let s = this.size;
      return Math.floor(l / s);
    },
    paginatedData() {
      let start = (this.pageNumber - 1) * this.size;
      let end = start + this.size;
      return getFullVendorList.vendors.slice(start, end);
    }
  }
}
```

For some reason I am getting an `undefined` error in the console as per the below:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js:588 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "ReferenceError: getFullVendorList is not defined"

found in

---> <Vendors> at client/ui/components/Vendors.vue
       <VkModal>
         <Root>
vue.runtime.esm.js:1736 ReferenceError: getFullVendorList is not defined
    at VueComponent.paginatedData (Vendors.vue?./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:71)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:3137)
    at Watcher.evaluate (vue.runtime.esm.js:3244)
    at VueComponent.computedGetter [as paginatedData] (vue.runtime.esm.js:3500)
    at Object.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:1915)
    at Proxy.render (Vendors.vue?./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js??vue-loader-options!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options:21)
    at VueComponent.Vue._render (vue.runtime.esm.js:4532)
    at VueComponent.updateComponent (vue.runtime.esm.js:2783)
    at Watcher.get (vue.runtime.esm.js:3137)
    at new Watcher (vue.runtime.esm.js:3126)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get it from instance reference

It should be like :

```
totalVendors() {
  return this.getFullVendorList.vendors.length;
},
```